# Place selectCheckboxes in selectList

Tags: selectlist, selectcheckboxes

I'm new in Apex / VisualForce, and I'm trying to place a long list of checkboxes in a "selectList display mode", ie. a vertical and scrollable display.

In practice, I've try something like this :

```
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedgroup}"  styleClass="form-control selectGroup"><apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!selectedgroup}"  styleClass="form-control selectGroup">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!buildWrapperAfterSelectChange}" rerender="theForm"/>
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!groupFilters}" /></apex:selectCheckboxes></apex:selectList>
```

or this :

```
<ul> <apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!selectedgroup}"  styleClass="form-control selectGroup">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!buildWrapperAfterSelectChange}" rerender="theForm"/>
    <li><apex:selectOptions value="{!groupFilters}" /></li></apex:selectCheckboxes> </ul>
```

but it doesn't work.
Thanks.

EDIT :

To be clearer, the final UI should look like exactly the same as a selectList, but with a checkBox at the right of each row of the list.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What should your final UI look like? Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just using Visualforce you cannot do this. You need to use jQuery or use some ready made API's available on Internet. One of such API is [Kendo UI](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/index).

[image]